# SQL server insert multiple rows and incrementing a int column

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment

I have some rows in a table and need to transfer them to another table. In the destination table i need also to add a field with an incremental value.

I'm doing the following, but i know that something in the insert is wrong, because the incremented value (intCodInterno) is always the same:

> ```
> INSERT INTO Emp_VISOT.dbo.TBL_GCE_ARTIGOS
>         ( strCodigo ,
>           strDescricao ,
>           intCodInterno ,
>           intCodTaxaIvaCompra ,
>           intCodTaxaIvaVenda ,
>           strCodCategoria ,
>           strAbrevMedStk ,
>           strAbrevMedVnd ,
>           strAbrevMedCmp ,
>           bitAfectaIntrastat
>         )(
>         SELECT  A.Artigo ,
>                 a.Descricao ,
>                 IDENT_CURRENT('Emp_VISOT.dbo.TBL_GCE_ARTIGOS')+1,
>                 '3' ,
>                 '3' ,
>                 '1' ,
>                 'Un' ,
>                 'Un' ,
>                 'Un' ,
>                 '0'
>         FROM PRIVESAM.DBO.Artigo A)
> ```

What do i need to change so the value is incremented correcty?

Thank you.

***EDIT:***

I made a small change in the query, and now it works.
I just insert a SELECT in the IDENT_CURRENT inside brackets:

```
(SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Emp_VISOT.dbo.TBL_GCE_ARTIGOS')+1)
```

I got all the rows that i need from the old table to the new with the incremented value.

Comment: If you use `IDENT_CURRENT` that would signify you have a `IDENTITY` column on that table; just do not specify that column in your list of columns and don't insert any values to it - an `IDENTITY` column will automatically get a new, unique value when an INSERT happens....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `IDENT_CURRENT('Emp_VISOT.dbo.TBL_GCE_ARTIGOS')+1` 
evaluated once when you want to run the query and all the rows will get the same id.

first solution is to iterate over the select result by a loop construct like cursor or whatsoever and insert the incremented index(you do that)

second solution is to make that column in destination table `identity`

Comment: Unfortunately in the destination table already exists a column with IDENTITY.

Comment: look for a way to use that column's value to be value of intCodInterno column, sth like a persisted computed column or ...

Answer (score 3):

Remove the part with intCodInterno and in SQL Server use the [Identity property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) to automatically increment it for you.

Answer (score 3):

IDENT_CURRENT won't update until the transaction commits, therefore its value remains constant until you insert.

Here are three options for fixing this issue:

1. Use some kind of counter (@newRowNum) such that for each row in your SELECT query, @newRowNum = @newRowNum +1, and thus your intCodInterno number = IDENT_CURRENT() + @newRowNum. This would probably require a lot of hacking to work though. Don't recommend it.
2. Insert your rows sequentially using the same business logic you have now - it will be tremendously less performant, however. Don't recommend it.
3. **Set that column in your destination table to be an identity column itself.** This is by far the best way to do it.

If you need a custom identity function (I assume there's a reason you're not using an identity column now), you can create one using some of the steps outlined above: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

In my case , i Inserted rows sequentially using the same business logic. I cannot use auto increment as i have to import old data also into this column. Once you have imported the data then u may go for updating the column for auto increment .